# Openshift App defaults back to php 5.3

Tags: php, openshift

I have a wordpress app hosted on openshift, deployed using the php-5.4 cartridge. As of today it is using the php-5.3 binary again, which throws a lot of errors. I have restarted the application as well as the php cartridge, still the same error. How can I fix this?

> which php
>
> > /usr/bin/php
>
> php -v
>
> > PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
> >
> > PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
> >
> > PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
> >
> > PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
> >
> > PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
> >
> > PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec  5 2013 07:09:40)
> >
> > Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
> >
> > Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: Contact the openshift support this is definitely not something that we can answer here right away

Comment: Well their forums are closed, and no response on IRC...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a temporary measure. Hopefully it helps in some way. I was having a similar issue with a Tiny Tiny RSS deployment. The actual application worked fine, I could navigate around my feeds etc., but the feeds wouldn't update due to the same PHP errors.

My feeds update via a cron job that would just call the .php file directly. So in this case my cron was performing the following:

`$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php/update.php --feeds`

The above used /usr/bin/php as you had stated above by default. I changed the above to:

```
/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php/update.php --feeds
```

Which fixed the issue. Hope this helps in some way...

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented something like this. So I am not the only one with this problem?

Comment: Nope, i created a new app and it doesn't have the same problem. Something changed along the way. Seems to be working with my "fix" for now anyway.